# unity using image to desplace score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We want the score displayed in our game to be a specifically designed number font.
We got the numbers in the format of png from `0`~`9` and I think it will be neat to put those in a `Texture[]` array and display it accordingly.

Following is the desplay controller script

```
public class StepDespController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static StepDespController instance;
    private int step = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    public Texture[] numberTextures;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    public void addStep(int step)
    {
        this.step += step;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        char[] array = step.ToString().ToCharArray();
        Debug.Log(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0 + i * 30, 0, 20, 30), numberTextures[(int)char.GetNumericValue(array[i])]);
        }
    }
}
```

And following is the binding of the textures of the digitals from `0`~`9`:

[image]

But I found it will not display anything in the game scene, what was I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem :

```
char[] array = step.ToString().ToCharArray();
Debug.Log(array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0 + i * 30, 0, 20, 30), numberTextures[(int)char.GetNumericValue(array[i])]);
}
```

Instead of doing it that way I would suggest you to simply use this :

```
const int offset_step = 30; // declare standard step size
int offsetX = 0; // declare starting x offset
foreach(char c in step.ToString()) // iterate through all characters in your score value as string value
{
    // draw texture on index `char - (char)'0'`
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(offsetX, 0, 20, 30), numberTextures[(int)(c - 0x30)]);
    offsetX += 30; // increase offset
}
```

To extend this answer a bit. `char` is 2 bytes wide numeric representation of character ( either printable or not ). Since you want to display only numeric values you have to remember that these values starts from `0` which is `0x30` and ends up with `9` which is `0x39` in ASCII and same within CP1251 which is used by C#. Now all you have to do, because your `0` texture is the "0th" element in your array, is to subtract beginning of the ASCII numeric characters from your character.

Simple example :

```
char zero = '0'; // 0x30
char one = '1'; // 0x31
// when you do `one == 1`
// it translates to  `0x31 == 0x01` which is false
// now consider this `one - zero == 1` 
// above will return true because 
// 0x31 - 0x30 == 0x01
// 0x01 == 0x01
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this, it helps, and there is a further question, what is the GUI stands for? I notice that the number will draw in the very front of the game scene, is there a single Global GUI or it just represent specific layer?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question right but  GUI in Unity is a special layer drawn after the whole scene is rendered. In the Camera inspector view you have to add GUI Layer to be able to render  GUI on that camera.

Comment: I just tried to delete the GUI layer Component from the main Camera I use, and It seems the Score Number will be displayed whether or not there is a GUI layer Component attached on that camera.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe that's something new in Unity 5+. Maybe it operates only on the layer values instead of Component. Try deselecting GUI Layer from layers section in Camera inspector view.